# IllegalArgumentException spring boot and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, illegalargumentexception

I have class same this:

```
public class DoctorCalender {
    private Long reservationId;
    private Date reservationDate;
    private String hospitalName;
    private String roomName;
    private Long capacityId;
    private List<Shift> shifts = new ArrayList<>();

    . . .

    public List<Shift> getShifts() {
        return shifts;
    }

    public void setShifts(List<Shift> shifts) {
        this.shifts = shifts;
    }
}
```

and I'm going to hql export mapping to above class with use this method:

```
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DoctorCalender.class))
```

and I get this error :

> IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [ir.sayar.hospital.toolBox.helperClass.DoctorCalender.shifts (expected type = java.util.List)]

Comment: share your hole stacktrace.

Comment: Maybe try to change your "List" to a "Set", the collection class used by Hibernate.

Comment: try this `.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DoctorCalender.class)).list();`

Comment: I'm trying that but I have same error again